# Use ResponseEntity object on angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

i didn't understood how to use the class of a ResponseEntity on Angular. For example, if I have something like this

```
@GetMapping("/path")
public ResponseEntity<A> f() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(A);
}
```

how do I use on angular the class A (and maybe its parameters) when I do a get call like this

```
f() {
        return this.http.get("/path");
}
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It will be a JSON in frontend and you have use JSON object represenation of class A

Comment: To which I access with the subscribe method, right?

Comment: Yes @Sfrizz_ you end subscribing like this f().subscribe(x=> console.log(x));